# C: Copy content of variable without reference

Tags: c

I defined a `display` function to display the content of a queue:

```c
void display(queue_t* s) {
    queue_t* c = s;
    int i = c->size;
    while (i > 0) {
        const char* elem = dequeue(c).value;
        printf("Item n°%d : %s\n",i,elem);
        i--;
    };
};
```

where `queue_t` is defined as follow:

```c
typedef struct queue {
    node_t* head;
    node_t* tail;
    int size;
} queue_t;
```

and `dequeue` is a function that removes a node from the queue and frees it. This function works as intended.

The function `display` should display the content of the queue without deleting its content but when testing it, the queue is empty if I call display before removing each element one by one by hand by calling `dequeue`. I thought that `queue_t* c = s;` would copy the element without any link between `c` and `s`.

**How can I copy the content of `s` into `c` without any link between the two variables ?**

---

**EDIT** - MWE

Header file - `queue.h`

```c
#ifndef QUEUE_H
#define QUEUE_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct element {
    bool type;
    const char* value;
} element_t;

typedef struct node {
    element_t content;
    struct node* previous;
    struct node* next;
} node_t;

typedef struct queue {
    node_t* head;
    node_t* tail;
    int size;
} queue_t;

queue_t* init_queue(void);

node_t* init_node(element_t e);

void queue(queue_t* s, element_t e);

element_t dequeue(queue_t* s);

void display(queue_t* s);

#endif
```

Source code - `queue.c`

```
#include "queue.h"

queue_t* init_queue(void) {
    queue_t* new = (queue_t*)malloc(sizeof(queue_t));
    new->head = NULL;
    new->tail = NULL;
    new->size = 0;
    return new;
};

node_t* init_node(element_t e) {
    node_t* new = (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    new->content = e;
    new->next = NULL;
    new->previous = NULL;
    return new;
};

void queue(queue_t* s, element_t e) {
    node_t* n = init_node(e);
    if (s->size == 0) {
        s->head = n;
        s->tail = n;
        s->size = 1;
    } else {
        n->previous = s->tail;
        s->tail = n;
        s->size++;
    };
};

element_t dequeue(queue_t* s) {
    if (s->size == 0) {
        element_t empty;
        empty.type = true;
        empty.value = "0";
        return empty;
    } if (s->size == 1) {
        element_t c = s->head->content;
        node_t* old = s->head;
        s->head = NULL;
        s->size = 0;
        s->tail = NULL;
        free(old);
        return c;
    } else {
        element_t c = s->tail->content;
        node_t* old = s->tail;
        s->tail = s->tail->previous;
        s->tail->next = NULL;
        s->size--;
        free(old);
        return c;
    };
};

void display(queue_t* s) {
    queue_t* c = s;
    int i = c->size;
    while (i > 0) {
        const char* elem = dequeue(c).value;
        printf("Item n°%d : %s\n",i,elem);
        i--;
    };
};
```

Test file - `test.c`

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "queue.h"

int main(void) {
    element_t e1 = {.type = false, .value = "1"};
    element_t e2 = {.type = false, .value = "5"};
    element_t e3 = {.type = false, .value = "10"};

    queue_t* test = init_queue();
    queue(test,e1);
    queue(test,e2);
    queue(test,e3);

    display(test);
    element_t e4 = dequeue(test);
    printf("%s\n",e4.value);
    element_t e5 = dequeue(test);
    printf("%s\n",e5.value);
    element_t e6 = dequeue(test);
    printf("%s\n",e6.value);
    element_t e7 = dequeue(test);
    printf("%s\n",e7.value);
    return 0;
}
```

Run the test file using

```bash
gcc -g -std=c99 -Wall -o test.o -c test.c
gcc -g -std=c99 -Wall -o queue.o -c queue.c
gcc -g -std=c99 -Wall -o test queue.o test.o
```

Comment: Why don't you just iterate over it, not using dequeue?

Comment: `queue_t* c = s;` initializes `c` as a copy of `s`.  But these are both *pointers*.  Copying a pointer gives you an independent pointer *to the same object*.

Comment: *"I thought that queue_t* c = s; would copy the element without any link between c and s"* - Wrong. You need to read about pointers.

Comment: I point to the same memory adress ! Thank you I understand my mistake here. I must perform a deep copy instead if I want to use dequeue ?

Comment: `queue_t c = *s;` might do it. Or not. You should provide a [mcve].

Comment: @hyde I provided a MWE with the test file and the complete definition of the structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues ...

1. You're leaking memory.
2. Passing structs *by value* doesn't *scale*.
3. `queue` does *not* set `next` for `s->tail` so forward list traversal doesn't work.
4. `queue` is much more complicated than it needs to be
5. `dequeue` should be split into two functions: `dequeue` and `destroy`
6. `display` should *just* display a list by *traversal*.
7. `init_node` should do a deep copy of `content.value`

---

You're *leaking* memory.

`dequeue` doesn't free `old->value`.

It returns a copy that has a valid `value`.

But, in `display`, you do:

```
const char *elem = dequeue(c).value;
```

You never free `elem`

Here is the `valgrind` output:

```
==2168790== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==2168790== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==2168790== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==2168790== Command: ./fix1
==2168790==
Item n°3 : 10
Item n°2 : 5
Item n°1 : 1
0
0
0
0
==2168790==
==2168790== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2168790==     in use at exit: 24 bytes in 1 blocks
==2168790==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 4 frees, 4,216 bytes allocated
==2168790==
==2168790== LEAK SUMMARY:
==2168790==    definitely lost: 24 bytes in 1 blocks
==2168790==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2168790==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2168790==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2168790==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2168790== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==2168790==
==2168790== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==2168790== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

---

`dequeue` returns "by value" -- this doesn't *scale*

Add `int data[10000000];` to `element_t` and watch the stack blow up ;-)

In general, passing around a `struct` by value has similar issues in other places.

---

`dequeue` should *just* dequeue the element.

Do *one* thing well. `dequeue` does a dequeue and a [partial/incomplete] destroy.

We should have a *separate* function `destroy` that fully frees the `node_t/element_t`

And, `dequeue` [as written] should be renamed as `pop` or `dequeue_back` because it works from `tail` to `head`.

Also, we'd probably like a `dequeue_front` that works from `head` to `tail`

And, it's much more useful if the functions return *pointers* to the dequeued elements and let the *caller* use `destroy` on them when the caller is finished with them.

---

`display` should just *display* the queue and *not* alter/destroy it.

It could be split [after fixup] into *two* functions (e.g.) `display_reverse` and `display_forward`

---

Here is the refactored code. It is annotated:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#ifndef DEEPCOPY
#define DEEPCOPY        1
#endif

typedef struct element {
    bool type;
#if DEEPCOPY
    char *value;
#else
    const char *value;
#endif
} element_t;

typedef struct node {
    element_t content;
    struct node *previous;
    struct node *next;
} node_t;

typedef struct queue {
    node_t *head;
    node_t *tail;
    int size;
} queue_t;

queue_t *init_queue(void);
node_t *init_node(const element_t *e);
void queue(queue_t *s, const element_t *e);
node_t *dequeue_back(queue_t *s);
void display_forward(const queue_t *s);
void display_reverse(const queue_t *s);

// prevent/reduce unintential "use after free"
#define FREE(_ptr) \
    do { \
        free(_ptr); \
        _ptr = NULL; \
    } while (0)

queue_t *
init_queue(void)
{
    queue_t *new = malloc(sizeof(queue_t));

    new->head = NULL;
    new->tail = NULL;
    new->size = 0;

    return new;
}

node_t *
init_node(const element_t *e)
{
    node_t *new = malloc(sizeof(node_t));

    new->content = *e;

// NOTE/FIX: we should deep copy the element
#if DEEPCOPY
    new->content.value = strdup(e->value);
#endif

    new->next = NULL;
    new->previous = NULL;

    return new;
}

void
queue(queue_t *s, const element_t *e)
{
    node_t *n = init_node(e);

    if (s->size == 0) {
        s->head = n;
        s->tail = n;
        s->size = 1;
    }
    else {
        n->previous = s->tail;
// NOTE/BUG: without this forward traversal doesn't work
#if 1
        s->tail->next = n;
#endif
        s->tail = n;
        s->size++;
    }
}

void
destroy_element(element_t *elem)
{

#if DEEPCOPY
    FREE(elem->value);
#endif
}

node_t *
destroy_node(node_t *node)
{

    destroy_element(&node->content);

    FREE(node);

    // convenience to caller
    return node;
}

node_t *
dequeue_back(queue_t *s)
{
    node_t *ret = s->tail;

    if (ret != NULL) {
        s->tail = ret->previous;
        if (s->head == ret)
            s->head = ret->next;
        s->size -= 1;
    }

    return ret;
}

void
display_forward(const queue_t *s)
{
    int i = 0;
    const node_t *node = s->head;

    for (;  node != NULL;  node = node->next) {
        printf("Item n°%d : %s\n", i, node->content.value);
        i++;
    }
}

void
display_reverse(const queue_t *s)
{
    int i = s->size;
    const node_t *node = s->tail;

    for (;  node != NULL;  node = node->previous) {
        printf("Item n°%d : %s\n", i, node->content.value);
        i--;
    }
}

int
main(void)
{
    element_t e1 = {.type = false,.value = "1" };
    element_t e2 = {.type = false,.value = "5" };
    element_t e3 = {.type = false,.value = "10" };

    queue_t *test = init_queue();

    queue(test, &e1);
    queue(test, &e2);
    queue(test, &e3);

    printf("display_reverse:\n");
    display_reverse(test);

    printf("display_forward:\n");
    display_forward(test);

    for (int i = 4;  i <= 7;  ++i) {
        node_t *node = dequeue_back(test);

        if (node == NULL)
            break;

        printf("main: %s (dequeue_back)\n", node->content.value);

        destroy_node(node);
    }

#if 1
    FREE(test);
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

---

In the above code, I've used `cpp` conditionals to denote old vs. new code:

```
#if 0
// old code
#else
// new code
#endif

#if 1
// new code
#endif
```

Note: this can be cleaned up by running the file through `unifdef -k`

---

Here is the program output:

```
display_reverse:
Item n°3 : 10
Item n°2 : 5
Item n°1 : 1
display_forward:
Item n°0 : 1
Item n°1 : 5
Item n°2 : 10
main: 10 (dequeue_back)
main: 5 (dequeue_back)
main: 1 (dequeue_back)
```

Answer (score 1):

> I thought that queue_t* c = s; would copy the element without any link between c and s.

No. It only makes a copy of the pointer `s` that you passed in the function.

Copying would require you to define "copy semantics", in other words:

- What happens if you copy a queue, will the "elements" in your queue be copied too? (This is trivial for primitive types, but not so easy for objects).
- If your elements are objects, what copy semantic do they have?

*(in the case of strings, you'll need something like `strncpy` or `memcpy` to copy all characters into a new buffer)*

Also, making a "true" (truly independent) copy you will need to make a complete copy of the entire queue.

This means setting up a completely new queue with all needed element data copied.

I'm phrasing it this way, because you certainly cannot re-use the `head`, `tail`, `next` and `previous` pointers from your existing queue, otherwise it would not be independent.

And... it's a bad design choice to have a method that is supposedly to be read-only* to modify your queue (data).

To display the contents of your queue you don't need to modify it.

**You need to be aware, especially in C, when, how, by whom and for how long your data structures are being accessed. Just a single dangling pointer makes your whole program unpredictable.**

**displaying data is considered a read-only operation by most (if not all) programmers.*

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I realize with this example how bad was my method and how bad I understand pointers.